# OLE DB Destination Editor not loading remote SQL table VS2008

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008, oledbconnection

I have a data flow task that shows the preview values for the flat file at the beginning, but at hte end for the ole db destination when preview is clicked nothing displays.  I am new to visual studio and C# both, and would appreciate any assitance I can provide.  WHen I run the whole solution, it completes normally (including writing to the log table in the same remotr SQL instance) but does not write any records to the SQL table.

I see I am not asking the correct question - the PREVIEW in the ole db destination editor is to preview the name of the table or the view you are loading into, and not the data you 
are loading from.

SO.. if anyone can help me with figuring out why the table is not being loaded but no errors produced I would appreciate it!

Thanks in advance!

Sandy